# No DSN drop down in Excel 2016 New Query

Tags: odbc, ms-office, excel-2016

My Excel 2016 doesn't have the DSN drop down list when creating a New Query to connect to an ODBC data source. It only shows the connection string option. How can I get it to show the option highlighted in the second image?

[image: Missing DSN Drop down]

[image]

Comment: I had this issue on my work computer. I solved it by copying a connection from a workbook with a working DSN connection and I recreate it each time in code (which is what I was doing anyway, just needed the first one after a new Excel install). So I haven't noticed if the issue still exists. The only possible reference I see to this implies that it's a bug that's fixed in a later version. I'll check my work computer and see if it's still an issue. It's not an issue on my home version of 2016  - 16.0.9126.2295.

Comment: Assuming this is on a Mac (you didn't say, and the screenshots are indeterminate)...  Please try updating your Excel to the [latest patch from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/release-notes-office-2016-mac).  Also update your Mac with [the latest iODBC driver manager for macOS](http://www.iodbc.org/dataspace/doc/iodbc/wiki/iodbcWiki/Downloads#Mac%20OS%20X).  You should then be able to access both User and System DSNs from Excel 2016.